# Edit HTML file and replace strings.How?

Tags: html, perl

I've a HTML file named "aud.html". I want to edit this file to search for a particular strings present in $stream_name variable and replace the same in the html file. below is my code, but it doesn't work. Any issue?

```
 $RESULTS_FILE = "/aud.html";
open OUT, ">>", $RESULTS_FILE or die "Could not open results file:$!";
$j=0; 
while($ln=<OUT>)
        {
                chomp($ln);
                print "Result file value is:$ln\n";
                if( $ln =~ m/$stream_name[$j]/ )
                {
                        print "Matched streamname with logcat file:$ln\n";
                        print "s/$ln/$stream_name NOT-RUN/g";
                        print OUT "s/$ln/$stream_name[$j]-NOTRUN/g";
                        $j++;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read file, replace text and write it to new html file:

```
$RESULTS_FILE = "aud.html";
open OUT, "<", $RESULTS_FILE or die "Could not open results file:$!";

my @a;   
while ($ln=<OUT>) {
    chomp($ln);
    for my $str (@stream_name) {
        if ( $ln =~ m/$str/ ) {
            $ln =~ s/($str)/$1 NOT-RUN/g;
        }
    }
    push @a, $ln;
}

open F, ">out.html" || die "$!";
for my $e (@a) {
    print F "$e\n";
}
close F;
```

Comment: Hi Massimo, Thanks. But the out.html file prints only first item from $stream_name and nothing else. Also all my FONT colors added in the html $RESULT_FILE file is also missing.

Comment: Thanks very much Massimo. It has almost worked:) But, if $ln matches @stream_name, it should replace the whole line present in $ln with "@stream_name : NOT-RUN" , but it giving as follows: 123.mp3 NOT-RUN NOT-RUN : PASS ... whereas i wanted as, 123 NOT-RUN

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$RESULTS_FILE = "aud.html";
    open(FILE, "<$RESULTS_FILE") || die "File not found";
    my @lines = <FILE>;
    close(FILE);

    my @newlines;
    foreach(@lines) {
       $_ =~ s/find/replace/g;
       push(@newlines,$_);
    }

    open(FILE, ">$RESULTS_FILE") || die "File not found";
    print FILE @newlines;
    close(FILE);
```